# Salesforce Lightning - Custom Labels with Parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, customlabel

When creating custom labels, you can do the following in a Lightning component (Assuming salutation = "Hello, {0}"):

```
{!format($Label.mySection.salutation, v.name)}
```

What I would like to know, is how to do this in javascript instead? I know the standard process to get the label is:

```
$A.get("$Label.mySection.salutation");
```

The part I am having trouble with is how to populate the parameter in the label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I now use the following function (taken from my comment on this answer):

```
format : function(string) { 
    var outerArguments = arguments; 
    return string.replace(
         /\{(\d+)\}/g, 
         function() { 
             return outerArguments[parseInt(arguments[1]) + 1]; 
          }
     ); 
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The release notes provided for the format function are much better than the actual documentation at this point: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_lightning_labels_dynamic_params.htm

You can use $A.util.format in JavaScript to get the same effect as {!format()}.

Comment: Now I use: format: function(string) {
        var outerArguments = arguments;
        return string.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function() {
            return outerArguments[parseInt(arguments[1]) + 1];
        });
    },

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use `$A.util.format` as it was never exposed. Apparently they made an mistake exposing the documentation. But it would be a really nice feature to have :( [here is the link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_additional.htm).

Comment: Currently only option is to use javascript `replace()` function

Comment: Correct. I use this function now: format: function(string) {
        var outerArguments = arguments;
        return string.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function() {
            return outerArguments[parseInt(arguments[1]) + 1];
        });
    },