# How can we Dynamically Populating Label Parameters in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

There was [a feature for an Aura framework which supported Dynamically Populating Label Parameters in Aura component syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_parameters.htm?search_text=format) providing functionality to format static label so that it is possible to specify "hello {0}" in the label text and display in UI "hello username" where username is current user name or any other populated value.

It is also confirmed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170629/is-there-a-format-function-available-in-a-lightning-component-controller-or-help) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188193/salesforce-lightning-custom-labels-with-parameters) that this was supported for the Aura framework. I expect this to be natively supported by LWC as well.

However, looks like there is no corresponding feature in Lightning Web Component syntax or I can't find any information about it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Technical duplicate of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/254811/2984), but cannot be closed as such because of lack of upvotes. As far as I can tell, we still don't have any such utility.

Comment: @sfdcfox, it is not, I am not trying to get here dynamic label, but rather use label as string format and supply parameters to a label like I could in Aura component

Comment: Makes more sense now. I was apparently not the only person who thought this, you might want to [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @sfdcfox ok, I have updated my answer. Maybe I have overestimated the familiarity with Aura framework features

Answer (score 3):

I think I will use the following workaround.

I would create a service LWC called `formatUtils`.

```
const format = (format) => { 
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
  return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
    ? args[number] 
    : match
  ;
});
};
```

and then use it

```
format( label, ['param1', 'param2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic importing for modifying custom labels isn't available [yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/#import).

[Another source](https://twitter.com/TheVishnuKumar/status/1107558419983032320).

Comment: I am not trying to import labels dynamically, i am trying to format static label so that I could have "hello {0}" in my label and display in LWC "hello Atlas" where Atlas is current user name or any other populated value. Dynamic import will not solve this problem

Comment: I understand, maybe you can getter and setters on your property to use/modify the label string?

Comment: I guess I would try to use some workaround like service component